# Kotlin - index of duplicate elements in an array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Is there an easy way to get the index of matching elements in an array without writing a for loop and then collecting the index?

```
Eg: val arr = arrayOf<Int>(2,3,4,2,5,2,6,3,2)

Output: For element 2, output should be (0,3,5,8) and For element 3, output should be (1,7)
```

Kotlin provides indexOf(element) which returns first index and then lastIndexOf(element) which will give me last index. Am looking for an easy way to get indexes of all matching elements.

***My solution: Standard solution of iterating over the array and collecting index.***

```
var indexArrOf2 = mutableListOf<Int>()
var indexArrOf3 = mutableListOf<Int>()
for(i in arr.indices) {
  if (arr[i] == 2) {
    indexArrOf2.add(i)
  }
  if (arr[i] == 3) {
    indexArrOf3.add(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: This may not be efficient at all, but you could do something like this: `arr.mapIndexed { index, value -> if (value == 2) index else null }.filterNotNull()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`mapIndexedNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-indexed-not-null.html):

```kotlin
arr.mapIndexedNotNull { index, elem -> if (elem == 2) index else null }
```

Answer (score 1):

A little convoluted but returns a map `Map<Element, List<Indices>>` to use as desired.

```
arr.mapIndexed { index, i -> i to index  }   //List<Pair<Int, Int>> - [(2, 0), (3, 1), (4, 2), (2, 3), (5, 4), (2, 5), (6, 6), (3, 7), (2, 8)]
.groupBy { it.first }   //Map<Int, List<Pair<Int, Int>>> - {2=[(2, 0), (2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 8)], 3=[(3, 1), (3, 7)], 4=[(4, 2)], 5=[(5, 4)], 6=[(6, 6)]} 
.mapValues { it.value.map { it.second } }   //Map<Int, List<Int>> - {2=[0, 3, 5, 8], 3=[1, 7], 4=[2], 5=[4], 6=[6]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [`withIndex()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html) extension function to add the index.  You can then select the matching items, and get their indices:

```
val arr = arrayOf(2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 2)

println(arr.withIndex().filter{ it.value == 2 }.map{ it.index })
// prints '[0, 3, 5, 8]'
```

Comment: I think filter and map will loop (total loop will be twice), this is not ideal its even less optimized than original OP's approach i'd suggest using sequences as this will loop through only one.